# Dynamically setting up the PayPal Checkout Transaction using JASON

Tags: paypal-sandbox

Depending on the goods being purchased I would like to create a JASON object to be placed into the Transaction area of the PAYPAL transaction. I keep failing no matter what I do. Following is the javascript code I am using to test:

```
    paypal.Button.render({
      env: 'sandbox',
      client: {
        sandbox: 'demo_sandbox_client_id'
      },
      payment: function (data, actions) {

        var oAmount = {}, 
            oAmount_details = {};
        oAmount.total = '30.11';
        oAmount.currency = "USD";
        oAmount_details.subtotal = '30.00';
        oAmount_details.tax = '00.11';
        oAmount.details = oAmount_details;

        return actions.payment.create({
          transactions: [{
            amount: oAmount
            /*  
                amount: {
                total: '30.11',
                currency: 'USD',
                details: {
                  subtotal: '30.00',
                  tax: '0.11'
                  }
                }
            */
          }]
        });
      },
      onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute()
          .then(function () {
            window.alert('Thank you for your purchase!');
          });
      }
    }, '#paypal-button');
```

*Note if you comment out:

```
   amount: oAmount
```

and then  uncomment:

```
            amount: {
            total: '30.11',
            currency: 'USD',
            details: {
              subtotal: '30.00',
              tax: '0.11'
              }
            }
```

then it will work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/750zb4up/32/)